# Check if the set is a subspace of vector space, determine a basis and its dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1. Check if the given set $U\subseteq V$ is a subspace of space $V$.
2. If it is, determine its basis and dimension.
3. If you say that some set is a basis, you must prove it.

a) $U=\{(2a,4b,a-3b,4a+5b:a,b\in\mathbb R)\},V=\mathbb R^4$

b) $U=\{(A\in V:S^{-1}AS \text{ is diagonal matrix})\},V= M_n$

Could you please show the steps for solving this problem?

Comment: Hint for (a): note that $(2a,4b,a-3b,4a+5b) = (2a,0,a,4a)+(0,4b,-3b,5b)$.  Hint for (b): Note that $S^{-1}(A+B)S=S^{-1}AS+S^{-1}BS$

Comment: A vector space doesn't have just one subspace. A subspace doesn't have just one basis. Hence my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Are all $u \in U$ elements of $V$

If $u,v$ are in $U$ is $u+v$ and $\alpha u$ in $U$?

Is $0$ in $U$?

a) 
For a basis there is one basis associated with $a$ and one associated with $b$

Show that these are linearly independent and span $U$

b) Is a little trickier but you should with some effort you should be able to find, $u,v$ such that $u+v$ is not diagonalizable.

Actually, I may be reading b) incorrectly.  Is it saying that $S$ is a given matrix in $M_n$ or there exists an $S \in M_n: S^{-1} A S$ is diagonal?

Comment: My initial interpretation of the second question was that $S$ is a given matrix at which point it will be a vector space, but I agree that it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do b).  Leave a) for you.

$U$ isn't a subspace, for any n...  The sum of two diagonalizable $A$ and $B$ is not necessarily diagonalizable. E.g. let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.  This is a counterexample for $n=2$.  There are also counterexamples for $n\gt2$.